# Dracaena hollow between stem and bark, is it dead?

Tags: plant-health, dracaena

One of my Dracaena stems has never quite managed to grow any leaves (there was a tiny shoot when I bought it but that soon vanished).  As you can see from the picture, there is a gap between the stem and the bark.  I've sawed the top off (that's what the blue is in the picture) to take a look inside the stem, but I have no idea what the inside is meant to look like.

Is this stem dead, or can I revive it - and how would I revive it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [Yucca elephantipes](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/68706/i-Yucca-elephantipes-i/Details) or the spineless Yucca.  They are easy to overwater and require high light from a southern or western exposure to do well.

The stump in the picture is dead.  When the bark is pulling away there is no transport of nutrients to anywhere above.  It may bud out from close to the base but this seems unlikely.

At this stage I would actually recommend getting a replacement plant and letting it dry out more between waterings.  If there is a reason to keep it I would just cut the stump off as close as possible to the soil line.  The other cane will continue to grow.

Comment: Ah, okay, a Yucca looks more like it.  It looks so similar to some types of Dracaena.  I thought it was probably dead.  I'll cut it off and see how the other stem does on it's own.